# java JSP Servlet Bean Calculator

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, javabeans

I have tried to write a Calculator with [JSP and a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484966/java-jsp-servlet-calculator) 
which is working perfect now. (with your help!)
Now I want to write it with MVC. 
So I have a JSP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Process" method="post">
    Enter a number: <input type="text" name="num1" />
    <input type="text" name="operand" type="submit "value="+" />
    <input type="text" name="operand" type="submit "value="-" />
    <input type="text" name="operand" type="submit "value="*" />
    <input type="text" name="operand" type="submit "value="/" />
    Enter a number: <input type="text" name="num2" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have the Servlet:

```
package controller;
import model.Calc;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/servlet")
public class Process extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public Process() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String num1= request.getParam("num1");
    String num2= request.getParam("num2");
    request.getParameter("operand");

    int num11 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    int num22 = Integer.parseInt(num2); 

    Calc calc = new Calc();

    calc.setNum1(num11);
    calc.setNum2(num22);

    request.setAttribute("calc", calc);
    request.getParameter("operand");

    request.setAttribute("operand", operand);
    request.setAttribute("calc", calc);

    request.setAttribute(calc.getResult());

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher =    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}}
```

And the JavaBean Class:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Calc implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int num1;
private int num2;
private int result;
private String operand;

public Calc() {
    super();
}

public Calc(int num1, int num2, int result, String operand) {
    super();
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
    this.result = result;
    this.operand = operand;
}

public int getNum1() {
    return num1;
}

public void setNum1(int num1) {
    this.num1 = num1;
}

public int getNum2() {
    return num2;
}

public void setNum2(int num2) {
    this.num2 = num2;
}

public int getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(int result) {

    if (operand.equals("+")) {
    result = num11 + num22;
    } else if (operand.equals("-")){
    result = num11 - num22;
    } else if (operand.equals("*")){
    result = num11 * num22;
    } else if (operand.equals("/")){
    result = num11 / num22;
    this.result = result;
}

public String getOperand() {
    return operand;
}

public void setOperand(String operand) {
    this.operand = operand;
}}
```

and this is the result:
it returns a 0 in the result field.

Thanks for your help!
[image: no error pic]

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: `Enter a number:` is better written like this : `<label for="operand">Enter a number</label>`

Comment: what about `Calc` class.

Comment: `action="Process"` where are you sending data too, ur servlet has a url pattern of `/servlet`

Comment: Sorry I translated the code from german to english for better understanding and I missed to translate the name.

Comment: @AlbertHoryza Could you explain de problem please? It is not clear to me.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="operand" type="submit "value="+" />` remove `type="text"`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your input tags to a select tag with options. Something like this

```
<select id="operand" name="operand" >
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="*">*</option>
  <option value="%">%</option>
</select>
```

Sometimes JSP tends to confuse, when their is the exact same name.